# A formula for $\lfloor n\rfloor+\left\lfloor \frac n2\right\rfloor+ \left\lfloor \frac n3\right\rfloor+\ldots+\left\lfloor \frac nk\right\rfloor$?

Tags: calculus, summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Is there any formula to calculate:
$$\lfloor n\rfloor+\left\lfloor \frac n2\right\rfloor+ \left\lfloor \frac n3\right\rfloor+\ldots+\left\lfloor \frac nk\right\rfloor$$
with $n$ and $k$  positive integers and $k\leq n$.

Comment: Is $[\cdot]$ the integer part?

Comment: @marcotrevi: Yes.

Comment: I doubt there is a nice formula for this. There are two regimes: as long as $k^2<n$, the quotients are strictly decreasing with decreasing steps; the sums will approximately follow an $n\log(n)$ curve; then the quotients start repeating longer and longer, with a unit step in between. The last "run" goes for $n/2\le k\le n$, with the sum linearly increasing.

Answer (score 5):

It  does not seem that there exists a closed formula. Indeed, let us denote the sum to be calculated by $S_{n,k}$. Specializing to the case $k=n$ corresponds to the entry [A006218](https://oeis.org/A006218) at OEIS, which only provides asymptotic estimates:
$$n \left(\ln n + 2 \gamma - 1\right)  - 4 \sqrt n - 1 \leq S_{n,n} \leq n \left(\ln n + 2 \gamma - 1\right) + 4 \sqrt n.$$

Comment: https://oeis.org/A006218 is not really the same thing, is it? The OP mentions several functions of $n$, one for each $k$.

Comment: @Ihf indeed, I will edit accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: @O.L.: what is $\gamma$?

Comment: @mac [Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).